# Angular 8 sidenavbar using bootstrap is not working properly

Tags: css, angular, sass, webkit, angular8

I have created a sidenav bar, but it is not working properly. The problem is height 100% is not being taken and it does not display the sidebar but a compressed version of it one might say.

In my HTML code I have defined, how my sidebar should function and in my SCSS file I have given out the styling for the navbar, the animation using webkit. But it is not showing properly at all.

My HTML code is:

```
<div id="wrapper"  [ngClass]="ref.click === true? 'toggled' :''" >
  <div class="overlay" [ngStyle]="{disply:ref.click === true? 'block' :'none'}" ></div>

  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
          <li class="sidebar-brand">
              <a href="#">
                 Brand
              </a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">Events</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">Team</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Works <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown heading</li>
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="https://twitter.com/maridlcrmn">Follow me</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <button appSidebar  #ref="appSidebar" type="button" class="hamburger is-closed" data-toggle="offcanvas">
          <span class="hamb-top"></span>
    <span class="hamb-middle"></span>
  <span class="hamb-bottom"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                  <h1>Fancy Toggle Sidebar Navigation</h1>
                  <p>Printing something here</p>                       
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
```

My SCSS code is:

````
body {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
body,
html { height: 100%;}
.nav .open > a, 
.nav .open > a:hover, 
.nav .open > a:focus {background-color: transparent;}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*           Wrappers            */
/*-------------------------------*/

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 220px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    left: 220px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -220px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: #1a1a1a;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#sidebar-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 220px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 70px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -220px;
}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*     Sidebar nav styles        */
/*-------------------------------*/

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    position: relative; 
    line-height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-nav li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 3px;
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
    -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
      -moz-transition:  width .2s ease-in;
       -ms-transition:  width .2s ease-in;
            transition: width .2s ease-in;

}
.sidebar-nav li:first-child a {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2):before {
    background-color: #ec1b5a;   
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(3):before {
    background-color: #79aefe;   
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(4):before {
    background-color: #314190;   
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(5):before {
    background-color: #279636;   
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(6):before {
    background-color: #7d5d81;   
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(7):before {
    background-color: #ead24c;   
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(8):before {
    background-color: #2d2366;   
}
.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(9):before {
    background-color: #35acdf;   
}
.sidebar-nav li:hover:before,
.sidebar-nav li.open:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in;
      -moz-transition:  width .2s ease-in;
       -ms-transition:  width .2s ease-in;
            transition: width .2s ease-in;

}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #ddd;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;    
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:active,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:focus{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 44px;
}
.sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: #222;
    box-shadow: none;
}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*       Hamburger-Cross         */
/*-------------------------------*/

.hamburger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;  
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
.hamburger:hover,
.hamburger:focus,
.hamburger:active {
  outline: none;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
          transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all .35s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px,0,0);
  -ms-transform:translate3d(-100px,0,0);
          transform: translate3d(-100px,0,0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all .35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-top { 
  top: 5px; 
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all .35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-middle {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}
.hamburger.is-closed .hamb-bottom {
  bottom: 5px;  
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all .35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-top {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all .35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-closed:hover .hamb-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all .35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top,
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;  
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-top { 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73,1,.28,.08);
  -moz-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73,1,.28,.08);
  -o-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73,1,.28,.08);
  transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73,1,.28,.08);
}
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-middle { display: none; }
.hamburger.is-open .hamb-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73,1,.28,.08);
  -moz-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73,1,.28,.08);
  -o-transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73,1,.28,.08);
  transition: -webkit-transform .2s cubic-bezier(.73,1,.28,.08);
}
.hamburger.is-open:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all .35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}
.hamburger.is-open:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px,0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-100px,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(-100px,0,0);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all .35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .35s ease-in-out;
}

/*-------------------------------*/
/*            Overlay            */
/*-------------------------------*/

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(250,250,250,.8);
    z-index: 1;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
     height: 100vh;
     ...
```

It's hard to say without to test your code (stackblitz)

Comment: this actually came pretty close to how I expected my sidenav bar to behave.